# Firebase authentication with multple providers

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a user authentication screen, so I decided to use Firebase.

However, I am facing a problem. Nowadays I have enabled 2 providers, which are:

```
1- E-mail/Password
2- Google
```

[Enabled providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2lsm.png)

I can create users perfectly.

When I create a user with `E-mail/password` option and use the Gmail address `guilherme.nunes@fover.com.br`, Firebase creates the user normally.

After using email, I am trying to use the second option of `Google` provider, using the same email. Now the old user is replaced with the new provider in Firebase.

[account created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnlBE.png)

After this, if I try to login with the first option (E-mail/Password) again, it says that the user does not exist.

I tried disabling the option to have 1 user per account, but then, Firebase creates 2 distinct users.

What I would like, is to link 1 account, with several providers.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the option to allow only a single account per email address, Firebase has certain providers that are preferred for certain email domains. Most notably: the Google provider is the preferred provider for `@gmail.com` addresses.

So in your initial process, you:

1. Register a user `something@gmail.com` with a email+password account.
2. Register a user `something@gmail.com` with a google account.

In this case, the second registration replaces/overrides the initial account.

---

What you want to do is **link the two accounts/providers** as described in the documentation on [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking). With this approach you don't fully register an account in step 2, but instead link the credentials for that second account to the email+password account that was already created for the user.

The documentation has a step-by-step explanation on how to do this. If you're having trouble making this work, post a new question with the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).